SMS not sending using sms messenger
I am using smsMessenger in my android application where user would enter number and after verification it will receive the otp. All the process is happening perfectly and toast of otp sent is being display. Now the issue is. When devices with android below 12 are using this application they are able to receive sms and some devices with android 14(like motorola and realme) are able to receive otp. but when it comes to MI devices like with android 12 or more and samsung device with android 14 are not able to receive otp. When I open the message application it comes in red stating sms not delivered.
All the permission have been granted in manifest file.
private void sendOtp() {
    try {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // Generate a random OTP
            otp = generateOtp();

            // Send the OTP via SMS
            SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
            smsManager.sendTextMessage(MobileNo, null, "Your OTP is " + otp, null, null);
            Toast.makeText(this, "OTP sent!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } else {
            // Permission is not granted, request permission
            requestsmspermission();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("TAGH", "print exception-" + e.getMessage());
    }
}

// Method to generate a random OTP
private String generateOtp() {
    Random random = new Random();
    int otp = 100000 + random.nextInt(900000); // Generates a number between 100000 and 999999
    return String.valueOf(otp);
}

